# Odd errors with connecting to AD - visual basic

Tags: sql, excel, vb.net, active-directory

Have couple of odd issues. I connect to AD to get the list of active users and their groups and write it out into the table in SQL. Code is written in Visual Basic. Occasionally I would get an error "There is no such object on the server". But when I try to run the same process 5 min later - it goes fine. In other words I do not get that error each time I run the process, only occasionally.
The other part of the issue - if I try to extract data from the sql tables and create excel file with the report - right after running the process above

I'm getting the error:

> System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
>     HResult=-2147467261
>     Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>     Source=System.Data
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper.InitializeAndCreateSession(OleDbConnectionString constr, SessionWrapper& sessionWrapper)
>          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
>          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)...

If I stop the processing, close out the windows app, re-open and run export to excel only - runs fine.
I thought that maybe memory was not released, but I do have commands in the end of processing that pulls data from AD:

```
dirEntry.Dispose()
dirEntry = Nothing
```

Is there special command to clear memory after connecting to AD? What can be causing those 2 sporadic errors? Thanks!

Per request - adding partial code.
- getting list of users and groups, then dispose dirEntry:

Public Sub ListAllADUsers(dirEntry As DirectoryEntry)
        Dim UserList As New Collection()
        Dim UsernameList As New Collection()
        Dim oresult As SearchResultCollection

```
    Dim dirSearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher("(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user))")
    dirSearcher.SearchRoot = dirEntry
    dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SAMAccountName")
    dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname")
    dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")
    dirSearcher.ServerTimeLimit = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
    dirSearcher.PageSize = 10000
    dirSearcher.ClientTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(12000)

    oresult = dirSearcher.FindAll()
    For Each result In oresult
        If Not result.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("cn").Value Is Nothing Then
           UserList.Add(result.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("cn").Value, result.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("SAMAccountName").Value)
           GetGroupsAD(result.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("SAMAccountName").Value.ToString(), result.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("cn").Value.ToString())
            If StopFlag = 1 Then Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    dirSearcher.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Can we see a snippet of your code? Even if it's been sanitized, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Well - resolved it. Had collections lists that I was going to use but decided not to. Once I commented it out - everything is working fine. Who knew it can mess up everything like that?? Closing. So if anyone would be using my code - just remove collections...